# StringJoin/FileNameJoin doesn't quite work in script

Tags: front-end, string-manipulation, files-and-directories, scripting

My mathematica script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/MathematicaScript -script

$HistoryLength=0;
    $pwf=FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[],FileBaseName[NotebookFileName[]]}];
$parameterfile=StringJoin[$pwf,".dat"]; 
Export["testcase.dat", {0.333, 100,0, 0, 35.1, 7.02, 0, 2, 1, 5, 10000}];
Export[$parameterfile, {0.333, 100, 0, 0, 35.1, 7.02, 0, 2, 1, 5, 10000}];
```

---

### It is also uploaded [**here**](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13223318/script_test_stringjoin.m)

All it does is creates a file name from the `NotebookDirectory` and `NotebookFileName` and saves a bunch of data `{0.333, 100,0, 0, 35.1, 7.02, 0, 2, 1, 5, 10000}` to file with generated filename.

It runs fine with the front end.

However, it doesn't run from a unix terminal which defeats the purpose of having this script.

The error that I get is:

```
> FrontEndObject::notavail: A front end is not available; certain
> operations require a front end.
> 
> FrontEndObject::notavail: A front end is not available; certain
> operations require a front end.
> 
> StringJoin::string: String expected at position 1 in
> FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[$Failed],
    > FileBaseName[NotebookFileName[$Failed]]}]<>.dat.
> 
> Export::chtype: First argument
> FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[$Failed],
    > FileBaseName[NotebookFileName[$Failed]]}]<>.dat is not a valid file
> specification.
```

Am I to understand that I will HAVE to use the front end for when I have `StringJoin` operations?

The reason I find `StringJoin` useful is that I have 150 different cases varying in parameters and easily identified by file name. If I can have a script to run all these mathematica cases, it would save a lot of trouble.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Off-topic Q: Is $HistoryLength=0 necessary in a script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at this

```
#!/usr/local/bin/math8.0.4/MathematicaScript -script

$HistoryLength=0;
$pwf=FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[],FileBaseName[NotebookFileName[]]}];
$pwf = "test";
$parameterfile=StringJoin[$pwf,".dat"];
Print[$pwf];
Print[$parameterfile];
Print[$InputFileName];
```

you will see that the Print statements work just fine - What requires the FrontEnd are the `Notebook*XY*[]` functions and since this is a script and not a notebook these are not avaiable. So you'd need to replace those. You could, for example, use `$InputFileName` and derive the information from that instead.

The last print will have the file name. Note that this is not an interactive session; then `$InputFileName` is ""

Comment: But `$InputFileName` is blank. How can I assign a value to it when the `Notebook***` functions don't work?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. However, I find that $InputFileName always has a file extension. Any way I could do away with that? The obvious way is to leave out the `.m` extension of my script.

Comment: `StringDrop[blah,-2]` is your friend.