# How to automate Mathematica scripts? - I

Tags: scripting

I would like to use the Windows Task Scheduler, or Visual Cron, to start a *Mathematica* notebook or .m file to do some system maintenance tasks: copy files from one place to another, etc.  How do I set up the notebook/file so it will execute when started without asking any questions?

I answered this question myself [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38888/how-to-automate-mathematica-scripts-ii).

Comment: I'll add an obligatory "_Mathematica_ is the wrong tool for this job" note. Also, AFAIK, it doesn't preserve/you can't modify file permissions when copying from one place to another natively — something I consider very critical when it comes to system maintenance tasks (maybe not for what you have in mind).

Comment: I use Mathematica in notebook form to do this kind of thing and it works nicely.  It's easy to use FileNames, Select, Union, Complement, StringReplace, etc. to handle the logic of what I want to implement.  I don't need to change the file permissions.

Comment: Perhaps useful: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9936/131

Comment: I suppose `Run` will always enable you to fill in the gaps.

Comment: I've just found [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9484/5478) are you familiar with this? It seems it is all you need.

Answer (score 3):

I can't help with the Windows part it, but I would imagine this is a two step operation. First, invoke Mathematica -- which you can do form the command line (or cron, presumably), as shown by the instructions [here](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/Mathematica.html), and have Mathematica open the desired notebook.

Once started, you can ensure that the commands will be run by using initialization cells, which automatically evaluate when the notebook is opened. Instructions for that are [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NotebookSecurity.html).

Comment: This is helpful.  Lot's of little details to work out here.  I'll post what I end up doing. In the meantime, if anyone has anything to add, I be grateful. I'm surprised that this isn't routine.

Answer (score 1):

I hope someone will post here an answer based on `InitializationCells` because I wasn't able to make them work for me.

This is quick walkaround:

```
DynamicModule[{},
          Framed["dir created"]
          , Initialization :> (   
CreateDirectory[FileNameJoin[{"C:", "Users", "Kuba", "Desktop", "dir1"}]];
CreateDirectory[FileNameJoin[{"C:", "Users", "Kuba", "Desktop", "dir2"}]];
 )
]
```

**Evaluate** this code (*Probably You will have to change "Kuba" in path* :)). **Save it** in trusted directory. **Create task** via Windows Task Scheduler to open this file.

Works for me.

**Big disadvantage** is that You have to evaluate code with all procedures.

**Quick solution** Put conditional construct in `Initialization` of this `DynamicModule`. It can check if there is directory called "ENABLED" in it's directory. There will not be such during first evaluation. Create manually directory "ENABLED" after saving main notebook.